# jQuery .find() returns values for "div" but not for "main" elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a piece of html (on a separate page, page2.php) like this:

```
<html><head>...</head><body>
    ...
    <main>
        <div>
            Hello
        </div>
    <main>
    ...
</body></html>
```

On page1.php, I'm trying to use a `$.get()` request to retrieve the page, then use `find` to get all the HTML inside of the `<main>` element:

```
$.get("page2.php", function (data) {
    var myData = $(data).find('main');
    console.log($(myData).html());
});
```

When I try this, the console displays "undefined."

However, when I change `find("main")` to `find("div")`, the console displays "Hello" as type String. Additionally, `find("header")`, `find("article")`, `find("footer")`, etc., all display String content on the console.

Is there something unique about `<main>` that is preventing this? Is it too new to the HTML spec?

Even trying to define the `<main>` element via an id, a la `<main id="main">` causes the console to display "undefined."

I'm looking for a specific answer to this problem; I'm not looking for an alternate way to do this, e.g. `load()`. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `filter()` rather than `find()` for root level elements.

`$()` strips out html and body tags, so your `main` is left at root level

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/q39Y3/)**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks, this worked! When I tried some other tests, I saw that other root-level (i.e. direct descendents of `body`) were not being found, as you suggested. I changed it to `var myData = $(data).find('main');` and am now getting the right HTML content.

Comment: also not uncommon to send partials in ajax with no body , and htis helps there also

Answer (score 1):

The `main` element is only supported in Chrome (v 26+) and Firefox (v 21+) so far.

If you parse the document using any other browser (or an older version of these), the browser will ignore the tag, or make someting different from it. The parsed document won't have any `main` element, as those browsers doesn't know of any such element.

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/main

---

Also, it seems that the `main` element has to be inside another element, for example:

```
<html><head></head>
<body>
  <div>
    <main>asdf</main>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This will find the element, at least in Firefox 25 where I tested it:

```
var html = '<html><head></head><body><div><main>asdf</main></div></body></html>';
alert($(html).find('main').html());
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/2gnS6/

Comment: Surprised to read that considering Angular.js ( developed by Google) uses any tag name and finds them based on js directives to compile them into templates you configure elsewhere.... very cool concept. Only caveats they suggest is polyfill for IE <9.

Comment: Very strange. I was also able to get it to work by wrapping `main` in `div` tags like you pointed out, but it just seems hack-y. Any idea why this is in issue, despite me trying it in Chrome 30 (and trying it with the html5shiv as well)?

Should I fall back to just using `<div id="main">`?

Answer (score 0):

It is a new feature of html5.
In fact, `<main>` is same as `<div id="main">`, so you can try to use `find('#main')` but not `find('main')`

Comment: It is not the same.  Do you have a source for that?